# User defined variable in postgresql query not working

Tags: postgresql

Please can anyone help to solve the problem of the PostgreSQL query? It's expected to return the result in the image but it returns nothing:

**Query:**

```
SET foo.date_1 = '2021-01-04';

select interface_name, max(time_stamp) as date, message,api_request from central  
where application = 'OMS to DW' 
and time_stamp like  ''''||'%' || current_setting('foo.date_1')||'%'||''''  
and message not like 'succe%'
group by interface_name,message,api_request
```

**Expecting:**

[image]

Comment: `LIKE` is for string values not for dates or timestamps

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show us some example input data? Your pattern is looking for literal ' marks in the `time_stamp` column, is that deliberate?

Comment: current_setting function returns text which is string so it's not problem. The exact problem is the extra code ''''|| and ||'''', if removing this, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help. The problem now it's solved, the correct code should be:

```
SET foo.date_1 = '2021-01-04';

select interface_name, max(time_stamp) as date, message,api_request from central  
where application = 'OMS to DW' 
and time_stamp like  '%' || current_setting('foo.date_1')||'%'
and message not like 'succe%'
group by interface_name,message,api_request
```